# Uploading coffeescript class based datastructure to ruby on rails 3 with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have a coffescript datastructure which consists of an object which has arrays of other objects, these objects have helper methods which make it easier to manipulate the data in the data structure:

```
class CrossData

  species_list: {
    species1: [21,10,30,40]
  }

  constructor: () ->
    @species = "defualt"
    @donors = [new CrossDonor] #array that will be full of CrossDonors

  helper_method: (arg1) =>
    #do stuff with crossdata

class CrossDonor
  constructor: () ->
    @name = "default"
    @linkage_group = -1
    @trait_cm = -1

  helper_method: (arg1) ->
    #do stuff with cross donor 

cross_data = new CrossData
```

if I try and upload this via jquery ajax ie:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
  beforeSend: (xhr) ->
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',
    $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')))

$.ajax(
  type: "POST",
  url: '/crosses/save',
  data: cross_data
  contentType: 'json'
  success: (msg) -> 
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg )
)
```

it doesn't work since it trips up over the functions, I guess the answer is to create a function which produces a json verison of the coffee script classes. I'm wondering if there is a jquery plugin which will give me a coffee_class data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do that might help you in the future would be to add a [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) method:

> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON` method when called will be serialized.

This is more or less like `to_json` in Rails. jQuery won't call it automatically, unfortunately, but the JSON library will and so will Backbone (if you end up using Backbone); adding a `toJSON` method also allows the object to control its own serialization.

Then add a `toJSON` call to your `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax(
  type: "POST"
  url: '/crosses/save'
  data: cross_data.toJSON()
  contentType: 'json'
  success: (msg) -> 
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg )
)
```

Or, with recent jQuery's, you could set up an [AJAX pre-filter](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Prefilters) to automatically call `toJSON` when it is available:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( (opts, original_opts) ->
    if(original_opts.data && original_opts.data.toJSON && $.isFunction(original_opts.data.toJSON)
        opts.data = $.param(original_opts.data.toJSON())
)
```

Then if you called `$.ajax` with a `data` that had a `toJSON` method, `toJSON` would get called to serialize the `data` object.

You could also set up a simple recursive `$.ajaxPrefilter` to automatically skip over anything in `original_opts.data` that [`$.isFunction`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) detected as a function. You'd want to use [`$.isPlainObject`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/) to skip over `data` that is already a string though.

I don't know of any plugins that do this automatically though.

Comment: Thanks useful to know about toJSON in other libraries, I called my function to_json, so will change that. Of course now the rails app doesn't get the data (the call hits the controller it just doesn't have any data in the params).

Comment: @jms301: Are they not in `params` or is it just a namespace issue inside `params`?